# Vuejs2 error when running Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Am running

```
npm run dev
```

Which in the package.json i have

```
  "scripts": {
     "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
```

},

So in my app.js am loading css via

```
require('vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css');
```

And now am getting an error

```
error  in ./node_modules/vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found
```

In my package.json i have installed loaders via

```
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"style-loader": "^0.20.1",
```

Further checking in `webpack.dev.conf.js` i can see

```
  const cssLoader = {
loader: 'css-loader',
options: {
  sourceMap: options.sourceMap
}
}

const postcssLoader = {
loader: 'postcss-loader',
options: {
  sourceMap: options.sourceMap
}
```

}

So what else do i need to add to have it run, so that i can use

```
require('vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css');
 or
import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css';
```

Am using the Vuejs2 webpack template

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a **postcss.config.js** file in your root directory like below.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 10 versions']})
  ],
};
```